# Unresolved reference when using class

Tags: python, class, methods, pycharm

I'm having an issue with my code. I'm currently learning Python and we have to create a class Student which needs to take the name, number, mid. grade and final grade of a student. We then need to define a method showing the average grade the student got.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, num, mid, fin):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
        self.mid = mid
        self.finale = fin

    def ave_stu(self):
        print((self.mid + self.fin)/2)
```

To add a student I use this afterward in the same page:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    stu1 = Student(Yann, 1, 67, 98)
    stu2 = Student(Bob, 2, 42, 12)
```

Where I wrote "Yann" and "Bob", PyCharm is telling me that I have an unsolved reference. Then, when I run the code, I received NameError: name 'Yann' is not defined.
I tried to use just a number instead and it worked. I then tried to put str(Yann) thinking it was an error of type, and it still didn't work.
So here's my question, is it a error of type, or am I just trying to pass something "illegal" in my class ?
Thank you!

Comment: This isn't really specific to classes. If you had tried `someFunction(Yann)`, You'd get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is it thinks you are calling the ***objects*** Yann and Bob when in reality you ment that they were strings.

Try this:

```
stu1 = Student("Yann", 1, 67,98)
stu2 = Student("Bob", 2, 42, 12)
```

Comment: That was quite a rookie mistake.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It happens. and its my pleasure ^_^

Answer (score 2):

String literals must be in quotes.

```
stu1 = Student("Yann", 1, 67, 98)
stu2 = Student("Bob", 2, 42, 12)
```